# DNS lookup is sometimes very slow

Tags: dns

So I figured out my problem finally through browser developer tools after weeks of scratching my head why sometimes some page loads are super slow.

I saw that DNS lookup is sometimes really slow (2-3 seconds).

What can I do to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: This will be entirely dependent on the DNS in use on your network/system and what your netowrk can or can't get to for DNS lookups.  What Ubuntu version are you currently running?

Comment: "other people have the same problem" - are you saying others on your network unrelated to your system?  A router wouldn't have *direct* access to install or downlaod things on your computer.

Comment: Can you perhaps answer my question?  We need to verify that the issue is actually you and not something else in your network.  If it's outside of Ubuntu and an issue in your network, that's going to be a lot harder to debug.

Comment: What sort of domains are you seeing the problem with? If these are locally-defined in your `/etc/hosts` file, be sure to have each domain/subdomain on its own line, even if you have multiple addresses going to the same IP. If your network has IPv6 support enabled, remember to include both the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. This has bitten me in the past when local development page loads were slow but the open Internet was fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had issues with `systemd-resolved` before. You can do the following:

1. Try disabling and stopping the `systemd-resolved` service:

   ```
   sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved
   sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
   ```
2. In the `[main]` section of your `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

   ```
   dns=default
   ```
3. Delete the symlink `/etc/resolv.conf`:

   ```
   rm /etc/resolv.conf
   ```
4. Restart `NetworkManager`:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
   ```
5. Then you can create `/etc/resolv.conf` with your preferred DNS server specified in there.
6. Finally, test and check if you are getting a better performance out if it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems in the past, with slow or even failing DNS lookups.

It turned out to be DNS problems most probably related to the "ADSL modem"-ISP combination, as **some** (but **not all**) DNS lookups were timing out.

So, the problems were not related to my Ubuntu OS (either 18.04 or 20.04);
**the remedy was to simply reboot my ADSL modem**.